# How to create mappings between different numbers?

Tags: java

I'd like to create a mapping for ratings based on numbers. Each "original" number should get assigned a bunch of "target" numbers

Similar to this:

```
 if (i = 2) return 3;
 if (i = 3) return 5;
 if (i = 4) return 7;
```

And so forth. How could I best write these sort of mappings, without having to repeatedly create ´if-return` statements?

Comment: Have you seen `java.util.Map` ? For Example `Map<Integer, Integer>` might help. Otherwise there is a `case` statement.

Comment: Use a Map to store the mapping.

Comment: How about using Switch Case statements ?

Comment: If you are dealing with just integers, you can keep things simple :  just use an array with arr[i] storing the value that i should get mapped to.

Comment: `return i+i-1;` If the pattern stays the same :)

Comment: @axiom That would not work if any of the numbers to map from are negative. It may not be practical if any of the numbers to map from are "large".

Comment: @BrettOkken Negative integers are not an issue, one just needs to add a suitable offset. You are right about large integers (how large depends on the amount of main memory, may/not be good enough).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Map<Integer, Integer> mappings = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
mappings.put(2,3);
mappings.put(3,5);
mappings.put(4,7);
System.out.println(mappings.get(2));
System.out.println(mappings.get(3));
System.out.println(mappings.get(4));
```

Answer (score 2):

For your problem, there are two main solutions.

The first one is to take the three pairs of numbers that you give and put them into a Map. A map associates a key with a value, so you would put each pair into your map

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> myMap = new HashMap();
myMap.put(myKey, myValue);
```

To get myValue from the map, you would access it through `myMap.get(myKey)`

The other way to do this is to note that the numbers that you give follow a function. 2x-1. You can create a function in the code to mimic this behavior

```
int myFunction(int value) {
    return 2*value-1;
}
```

Just call this function and you will get the correct output. For example `myFunction(3)` will return 5.